# Is it safe to turn on unattended upgrades for a live Ubuntu Webserver (Nginx/Apache)?

Tags: server, upgrade, apache2, nginx, unattended-upgrades

I was wondering whether it is safe to have the `unattended-upgrades` package keep the system up to date on a live webserver.

Here I am specifically wondering whether issues might occur when packages such as **nginx** or **apache2** update configuration files.

I'd expect the updater to just go with the defaults, as when you do manual upgrades and retain existing configuration. I am worried however that upgrades might arbitrarily break servers when there's a major version update of some package or other.

I run a lot of servers, so this scenario could evolve into a very bad day quite fast :)

Any experiences you could share here? Is it generally a good or bad idea to do this? Is there an easy way to get the `unattended-upgrades` package to send a report of what has been upgraded and if any issues cropped up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unattended-upgrades` caused apache2 to go offline for me recently. After digging around I realised the unattended upgrade of some php7.0-* packages were the cause.

I'm still on the fence as to whether the benefits of unattended upgrades outweigh the costs when it inevitably does go wrong one day - that will depend on what you're using the server for I guess and your risk appetite ;)

In my research I came across the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` config file which has settings that will let you add an email address for the package to send you a report each time automatic upgrades are performed.

You need to add the line to the config file (you'll need a mail package installed too to actually send the email):

`Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "me@example.com";`

Further details of the config file are available:
https://gist.github.com/roybotnik/b0ec2eda2bc625e19eaf
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates

The `unattended-upgrades` package also leaves a trail of what it's done in the logs: `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/` as well as `/var/log/apt/`.

Comment: Thanks @jt_uk yeah that's what I was worried about. I think I'll stick with manual upgrading and just leave security upgrades enabled :)